# How to avoid "Type mismatch" in static generic factory method?

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

Either I'm too stupid to use google, or nobody else encountered this problem so far.

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
public interface MyClass {
  public class Util {
    private static MyClass _this;
    public static <T extends MyClass> T getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
      if(_this == null) {
        try {
          _this = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      return _this;
    }
  }
}
```

Howerer, in the line "return _this;" I get the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyClass to T"
Why is this? T extends MyClass, so where is the problem? If I change the line to "return (T)_this;", i just get a warning about the unchecked cast, but I don't like warnings ;-) Is there a way to achieve what i want without an error or warning?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: naming a static var `_this` sounds like asking for trouble

Comment: @MatrixFrog - *sigh* i wanted a factory in the interface so i dont have to write one for every implementing subclass. you can laugh now ;-)

Comment: @matt b: Naming an interface MyClass is also asking for trouble!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine you have two implementations of `MyClass`, `Foo` and `Bar`. As a field of type `MyClass`, `_this` could be a `Foo` or a `Bar`.

Now, since your `getInstance` method returns `<T extends MyClass>`, it's legal to call it any of these ways:

```
MyClass myClass = Util.getInstance(MyClass.class);
```

This doesn't work if it's the first call, because `MyClass` is an interface and can't be instantiated with `newInstance()`.

```
Foo foo = Util.getInstance(Foo.class);
Bar bar = Util.getInstance(Bar.class);
```

Now, what would happen if `_this` was an instance of `Foo` and you called `Util.getInstance(Bar.class)`? That's why you aren't allowed to do this.

Comment: wow, looks like i made a huge error in reasoning there. considering this, it wouldnt have worked the way i want anyway. thanks for the explanation.

Comment: +1: Good explanation. I have one nitpick; You say "Imagine you have two **subclasses** of `MyClass`". Since `MyClass` is actually an interface, not a class, can you change the word "subclasses" to "implementations"? And then in the next sentence, you go on to say that "`_this` could be a `MyClass`, a `Foo` or a `Bar`. But in fact, it's **always** a `MyClass`. In addition to being a `MyClass`, `_this` could be a `Foo` or a `Bar`.

Comment: @Asaph: Good point. My explanation treated `MyClass` as if it were a concrete class. It being an interface also raises another issue which I've edited my answer to mention.

Comment: In your defense, the interface was called MyClass.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the variable `_this` is of type `MyClass`, not type `T`. Even though it happens to contain an instance of `T`, the compiler doesn't have a way of knowing that.

Answer (score 2):

I just verified that this makes the compiler happy and still constrains types in the manner that you want:

```
public interface MyClass {
  public class Util {
    private static MyClass _this;
      public static MyClass getInstance(Class<? extends MyClass> clazz) {
        if(_this == null) {
          try {
            _this = clazz.newInstance();
          } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        return _this;
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit:

Thinking about the client code, this actually just exposes a bug in the design of this factory. Imagine this:

```
MyClass foo = MyClass.getInstance(Foo.class); // sets _this to a Foo and returns it

MyClass bar = MyClass.getInstance(Bar.class); // _this is already set to a Foo and
                                              // we return a Foo when we probably
                                              // are expecting a Bar!
```

Comment: But then the method explicitly returns an instance of a `MyClass` and the client would have to do the cast on the outside instead, right?

Comment: @aioobe: There'd be a `ClassCastException` waiting to happen if they did cast.

Comment: My assumption is that the client code assigns the return value to something with type `MyClass`.

Comment: I don't get it. If you say `getInstance` returns a `MyClass` then you'd have to cast the result to the desired type on the *outside*. Why wouldn't you want to say that it returns a `T` and do the cast on the inside?

Comment: @aioobe: If you only ever call `MyClass` methods then there is no need to cast on the client side. Without seeing some client side code, it's impossible for us to know the use case. Actually, looking at it further, I see that `MyClass` is an empty interface... Hmm... I think the whole example is somewhat broken anyway (see my latest edit).

Comment: @aioobe: Would it help if I pointed out the fact that MyClass is actually an interface? Due to the confusing name, you may have thought it was a class. Doesn't not casting seem like a good idea? If you called a method that returned a List would you cast it into an ArrayList? Probably not, right?

Comment: Ah, but what if I want to do `Foo foo = MyClass.getInstance(Foo.class);`?

Answer (score 1):

#### The "Type Mismatch"...

...is due to the following:

- `T` represents a subclass of `MyClass`.
- `getInstance` is declared to return an object of type `T`
- It returns an object of type `MyClass`.

It's like declaring a method to return a `Double` while it returns some `Number`.

#### The solution...

... is to change the return statement to

```
return (T) _this;
```

(and add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` if you want to get rid of the warning).

#### But there's a problem...

As ColinD points out: Suppose you have

```
class MyClassImpl1 implements MyClass {
}

class MyClassImpl2 implements MyClass {
}
```

and do the following:

```
MyClassImpl1 o1 = MyClass.Util.getInstance(MyClassImpl1.class);
// _this now holds a value of type MyClassImpl1...

// ... which causes this line to throw a ClassCastException.
MyClassImpl2 o2 = MyClass.Util.getInstance(MyClassImpl2.class);
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea; the method signature lies about what it can do.

Comment: Hmm.. could you explain what you mean by that? (Forgive me if I'm being slow here.)

Comment: Sorry. I just read your answer for like the third time and I see what you mean... I'll update my answer.